# Allow users to hide question Oneboxes that contain ignored tags

Tags: feature-request, chat, spoilers, chat-feed

This is particularly relevant on this site,  where it's easy for a new movie or TV series to come out and appear in a chat feed,  and spoil you.

I've made this as a post on this site not the main meta, as it's something I don't think would be as useful on other sites besides Movies & TV.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure this has been requested one bozillion, gazillion times. The answer is "***no***".

Answer (score 1):

As a work around, we could create specific feeds with their own user for a "hot" tag, then exclude those tags from the regular feed. That way, both unspoilered fans and uninterested non-fans can ignore that user.

For instance, we could have users

- @R2-D2 for [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars)
- @Dumbledore for [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter)
- @Data for [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek)
- @ID10T for [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification)
- @Obie and @MetaObie for the rest

Now that *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* has been released, users should then ignore @Dumbledore (or possibly @Newt as well, who's posting specifically [fantastic-beasts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantastic-beasts)).

Comment: How would [tag:story-identification] questions be spoilers?

Comment: @RandalThor it may be a subject one may wish to ignore.

Comment: Wouldn't this backfire really easily due to people having those usernames or am I misunderstanding something fundamental about your answer.... I know there is already problems in chat with finding a user by username and/or pinging wrong users.

Comment: @Erik I _think_ ignorance is by user ID, not by handle.

Comment: @SQB great if that's true then it would completely alleviate my concerns